# Какие знаки препинания ставят в выражении "Ну нет так нет"?

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания ставят в выражении "Ну нет так нет"?

Answer (score 1):

По-разному можно, в зависисмости от акцентируемого слова:

**Ну нет - так нет.

Ну нет, так нет.

Ну, нет - так нет.

Ну нет, так - нет.**
И еще много всего. В обычном употреблении я бы выбрал первый вариант.